# Scss to css in angular while compiling

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, sass, command-line-interface

I need some help.

I'm looking for a way to generate (or update if the file already exists) a .css file that is a conversion by an .scss file. All of this when compiling.

Explaining this in a better way :

I'm writing some code, everything is ok and I decide to save. Perfect. ctrl+s and the app run perfectly. Nice. Now I've added a style.scss file somewhere (it doesn't really matter the path). How do I "tell" to the compiler that everytime he compile he also has to 'take' this .scss file, convert it in a .css file, and put it in a specific path?

Comment: @Konafets I don't quite know where to start, sincerly. I've my .scss and a folder where I want the compiler generate my .css. That's everything I have

Comment: Many of the common compilers have 'watch tasks' that you can implement where you configure a directory or set of files to 'watch' for changes.

Comment: @RobertWade Can you provide me something more specific? I've searched a lot without finding anything relevant to my problem.

Comment: I'm looking to compile & 'translate' this sass file into a css file whenever I do a simple `ng s`

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found a way to do what I needed to do.

I've created my `gulpfile.js` in this way :

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');

gulp.task('styles', function () {
    gulp.src('src/app/sass/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./css/'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch('./sass/**/*.scss', ['styles']);
});
```

And added this command to `package.json` :

`"try": "gulp watch && ng s"`

the problem is that if in the cli I run the command `npm run try` it will never start my application, because the `watch` is an endless stream.

How can I have the watch and the app running both at the same time?

*Edit

Found the solution using `concurrently`